# Why multiplicity.SIMPLE edges cannot be included in vertex-centric indices?

Tags: graph, graph-databases, titan, multiplicity

I have an Edgelabel

`ContainsAttribute` which has `Multiplicity.SIMPLE`

These edges also have a property let's call it `x` that I want to make the vertex-centric index on.

```
PropertyKey propertyX = mgmt.getPropertyKey("x");
EdgeLabel containsAttributeLabel = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel(EdgeLabels.ContainsAttribute).multiplicity(Multiplicity.SIMPLE).make();
mgmt.buildEdgeIndex(containsAttributeLabel,"propXIndex",Direction.IN, propertyX);
```

So the edges represent `Entity --containsAttribute --> Attribute`. The query I am trying to make will try to search Entities given queries by filtering on the Property `x`.

I wonder why it doesn't allow me saying:

`The relation type [ContainsAttribute] has a multiplicity or cardinality constraint in direction [IN] and can therefore not be indexed`

I think my use case makes sense and I wouldn't want to relax my edge label multiplicity from `SIMPLE` to `MANY2ONE`,`ONE2MANY` or `MULTI`, to make it work.

**Edit:** According to the example http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html Hercules battled a lot of monsters so the edges labeled 'battled' are found coming out of 'Hercules' multiple times connecting with different monsters. Then the edge index is on attribute 'time' so filtering can be done. I want to do something similar and I thought vertex-centric indices are the way.. Those edges are Multiplicity.SIMPLE because there is at most one edge labeled 'battled' between Hercules and each of the monsters.

**Edit 2:**

Similar to the given example again a SIMPLE graph:

[image]

I believe it would make sense to have a vertex-centeric index for Hercules and the out-going SIMPLE 'battled' edges. That would make queries like `time >=20` faster when traversing from Hercules to the monsters.

I don't understand why we must have a MULTI graph (less strict) like below to leverage vertex-centric indices..

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I removed my answer. Looked at it again in more detail and yes, you're absolutely right. Indices would make sense in certain scenarios. You should create a ticket in Titan's issue tracker (if not already done).

Comment: @DanielKuppitz Thanks for looking into that again! It was strange to me why I needed to lossen the constraints of my graph for it to work :) - here is the issue I have filed https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/1275

Comment: @DanielKuppitz I assume this is no longer a problem with DSE Graph right? Thanks!